# "Coverage information was not collected." when running 'gradle sonarRunner' after generating Jacoco reports

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I've started with the 'java-gradle-simple' example from the Sonar GitHub repo:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/gradle/java-gradle-simple

I've added the jacoco plugin to my build.gradle file in an empty to see unit test coverage results, and I'm seeing the warning:

> Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include
>   debug information into compiled classes?

I'm currently running version 4.3.2 of Sonar, and this is what I'm seeing after running 'gradle test jacocoTestReport sonarRunner':

[image: Sonar report]

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

allprojects {  
  ext.baseVersion = "0.1"
  ext.snapshotVersion = true

  group = "org.sonar.tests"
  version = "$baseVersion" + (snapshotVersion ? "-SNAPSHOT" : "")
}

sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "Simple Java Gradle Project"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "org.codehaus.sonar:example-java-gradle"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
        property "sonar.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/classes"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-jacoco:0.1.0' }
}

test {
  ignoreFailures = true
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Is there some other configuration that I'm missing?  Surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be much information on generating unit test coverage with Sonar using Gradle.

Comment: What jdk version are using? Jdk8 requires a newer version of jacoco than the one provided in gradle.

Comment: @StavSaad I was indeed using JDK 8.  After switching to JDK7, I'm able to see unit test coverage in my local Sonar instance.  Is it possible to set the jacoco version that gradle is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jdk 8, you should add the following block to your gradle script:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
}
```

Also, you should make sure your sonar version supports jdk8

Comment: Going back to JDK8 and specifying toolVersion brings me back to my original "Coverage information was not collected" warning and no unit test coverage reported on Sonar.

Comment: @chazzlabs Try this tool version: 0.7.2.201409121644. Do you get jacoco.exec files generated now?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that after trying the version you mentioned in your answer I did try the newest version of jacoco and still had no luck.

Comment: @chazzlabs check your `build/jacoco` directory. Are there any exec files there? If yes, check that their name is `test.exec` as in your sonar config.

Comment: Yes, build/jacoco/test.exec is being generated.  Is there anything specific to Gradle that I might be overlooking?  For example, is it necessary to declare jacoco{} in a particular order in relation to other tasks?  Is it possible to verify that Gradle is in fact using the version of jacoco that I'm telling it to?

Comment: @chazzlabs This means jacoco is not the source of the problem anymore. Try checking for the path to the jacoco report for sonar and see if it fits the exec files. If not, check for your sonar version support of java 8

Comment: It looks like the version of the Sonar Java plugin that was being used by my Sonar installation did not support Java 8.  Updating the plugin to a more recent version fixed my issue.  If you'd like, you can post this as an answer here and I'll accept it.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Edited the existing one.